# Dynamic chart from database

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I would like to create a dynamic graph from my database. The graph only takes into account the last values of my database, so my graph contains only one value instead of the entire database.

I use javascript and Google Charts API

```
function donutdraw() {
    $.ajax({
    url : 'bdd.php', // requesting a PHP script
    dataType : 'json',
      success : function (data) { // data contains the PHP script output
      var partie = data.partie;
      var partiecount = data.partiecount;


        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
        ]);
        data.addRows(2);

        for (var i = partie.length; i >= 0; i--) {
          for (var i = partiecount.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            var nb = 0;
            data.setCell(nb,0, partie);
            data.setCell(nb,1, parseInt(partiecount));
            nb = nb + 1;
          }
        }

        var options = {
          title: 'Répartition des attaques',
          pieHole: 0.4,
          width: 600,
          height: 400,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("donutchart"));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        },
    })

}
```

```php
    //GRAPHE 5
    $grap5rep1 = $bdd->query('SELECT Cible AS partie FROM Mail GROUP BY Cible');
    $grap5rep2 = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(Cible) AS partiecount FROM Mail GROUP BY Cible');


    while ($donnees = $grap5rep1->fetch()){
     $partie=$donnees['partie'];
    }
    $grap5rep1->closeCursor();

    while ($donnees = $grap5rep2->fetch()){
     $partiecount=$donnees['partiecount'];
    }
    $grap5rep2->closeCursor();
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: what do I have to do to have my entire database in the graph and not just the last line ?

Comment: Just a guess, but probably not redeclare and overwrite the `data` variable.

Comment: What should I change? i don't get it.